# Geometric multiplicities of the same eigenvalue of $A$ and of $A^T$

Tags: matrices

1. For a square complex/real matrix $A$, $A$ and $A^T$ have the same
   set of eigenvalues, each with same algebraic multiplicities, since
   their characteristic polynomials are the same.

   I wonder for each eigenvalue, are its geometric multiplicities for
   $A$ and for $A^T$ the same?
2. Similar question for $A$ and $A^H$, where $H$ means conjugate and
   transpose, and the relation between their eigenvalues is conjugate.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that if $J$ is the Jordan form for $A$, then $A^t$ is similar to $J^t$.

Comment: @Gerry: Thanks! Although $J^t$ or $J^H$ may not be a Jordan form, it seems that geometric multiplicity stays the same for the same/conjugate eigenvalue?

Comment: Think about why $J$ gives you information about multiplicities, and whether you can extract the same information from $J^t$ (or $J^h$).

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another attempt:

First note that for a square matrix $M$, we have $\dim \ker M = \dim \ker M^T =\dim \ker M^*$.
Hence $\dim \ker (\sigma I-M) = \dim \ker (\sigma I-M)^T = \dim \ker (\sigma I-M^T)$, and $\dim \ker (\sigma I-M) = \dim \ker (\sigma I-M)^* = \dim \ker (\overline{\sigma} I-M^*)$.

The geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ is $\dim \ker (\lambda I -A)$.

It follows that $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of geometric multiplicity $k$ iff  $A^T$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of geometric multiplicity $k$.

It follows that $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of geometric multiplicity $k$ iff  $A^*$ has an eigenvalue $\overline{\lambda}$ of geometric multiplicity $k$.